# MySQL Interval - bring in users that have not logged in for 6 months

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query:

```
    $query1="SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE now() < (last_login + INTERVAL 6 month)";
$result1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){  

    $inactive_accounts[] = $rows['ID'];
}
```

I want it to pull in all user_id's of people who have not logged into their account for 6 months. I have it set so when they log in, it inseerts datetime into the last_Login column.

I just wondered if this SELECT query was ok, as I am having trouble testing it. Will this show ID's of people who have not logged in for 6 months?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right lines. What you probably need is something like the [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function in MySQL, so

```
SELECT *
FROM wp_users
WHERE last_login < DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH )
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it. Note that the `6 MONTH` adjustment is made to `NOW()`, not `last_login`. This means that the optimiser can use an index that has last_login as the first or only field.

Comment: @nnichols Thanks for picking up the typo.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE last_login < date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 6 month)
```

Comment: I think it's way easier to read and more clear what's the intention.

Comment: Out of my head I'm not sure if (last_login + INTERVAL 6 month) would work. That's what the date_add() and date_sub() functions are for.

Comment: There is no need to use DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB. Personally, I prefer the shorthand method using +/-. But the comparator is wrong, it should be `<` (less than).

Answer (score 0):

To test that your code works, manually tweak a user's last_login field and set it to > 6 months ago.  In your development environment of course!